# Tekton: Get Pipeline name inside task

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

I [know](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/variables/) that there is something like `context.pipelineRun.name` but that's only available in the pipeline. How can I get the pipeline name inside a task to build a link to the Tekton-dashboard, WITHOUT a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

From Tekton's documentation (https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/variables/) the name of the pipelinerun is not available in the task.
So, I see only the possibility to pass it as a parameter from the pipelinerun (where it is available under `context.pipelineRun.name`). Or you use the task's name (`context.taskRun.name`), if that is sufficient for you.

Answer (score 0):

As what I know

```
context.pipelineRun.name
```

should work in your Task, if your Task is executed in a PipelineRun - since Tasks is the way to execute things in a Pipeline. Although, this variable will not be available if you run your Task *standalone*.

Comment: Can I "access" this inside the task or do I have to pass it into the task as a param?